# Combination of at most one of the oldest 2 players

Tags: combinations

11 players must be selected from 15 players.
(i) Find at most one of the oldest two players must be included.
Please help with full annotation, thnx

Comment: Two cases: (i) None of oldest two is included or (ii) exactly one is. **Or else:** Count the number of unrestricted choices and subtract the bad ones (both oldest are included). The number of bad choices is $\binom{13}{9}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, 15 players are composed of the 2 oldest and 13 younger players.

Ways to select 1 of the oldest and 10 of the younger: ${2 \choose 1}{13 \choose 10}$

Ways to select none of the oldests and 11 of the younger: ${2\choose 0}{13 \choose 11} = {13 \choose 11}$

Sum them to select at *most* one of the oldests among 11 selected players: ${2 \choose 1}{13 \choose 10}+{13 \choose 11}$

$${2 \choose 1}{13 \choose 10}+{13 \choose 11} = \frac{2!13!}{10!3!}+\frac{13!}{11!2!}=650$$